# Xbox app on Windows 10 saying "Server connectivity: Blocked"; Teredo seems to be working fine though

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, xbox360, teredo

"Server connectivity: Blocked" is the error I receive on the Xbox app:

[image]

Now when I try troubleshoot, 99% of the fixes I see online are to do with NAT status, but as you can see here, my NAT type is "cone", which means it should be working just fine. I also have all the correct ports forwarded:

[image]

I recently had this problem about a week ago, reinstalling Windows fixed it for about 4 days, but now it’s back, I don’t really want to keep reinstalling Windows every time this happens, hoping someone somewhere has a fix for this

Comment: Makes me wonder if your network card is going bad.

Comment: i don't have one, i use ethernet directly into the router, my motherboard doesn't support wifi

Comment: Yes, your network is built-in to your mainboard, but it's still a "NIC", a "Network Interface Card". USB-network dongles are inexpensive and can help isolate the issue by removing your on-board network from the loop. If the USB-network dongle works, the problem was with your onboard NIC. If it doesn't, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: ok, ill buy one tomorrow and see if that fixes it, part of me is hoping it does since then i know whats wrong, other part doesn't, as motherboards aren't exactly cheap...

Comment: Well, the good news is that you can just keep the USB-NIC dongle and use it. No need to replace the MB just because one component has failed.

Comment: Not really. I've only worked with the devices Dell packages with some of their more compact systems personally. They look similar to this: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833114074